# Eclipse is not accepting openjdk as JRE

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having dificulties to start an RCP Application in Eclipse (2022-09).

I pointed the installer to my open JDK installation (https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/17) at C:\software\jdk-17. I'm using this JDK for maven, java on the command line an also for IntelliJ without any problems.

Also Eclipse can import and compile my RCP Application consisting of ~20 Pluginsand without problems. No red dots, everything fine.

But as soon I'm starting my RCP application, I get a "Cannot locate JRE definition: "openjdk17". Launch aborted." error.

This is my configuration:
[image]

Any ideas what's missing?

**Edit**: Requested "Installed JREs"
[image]

Comment: What did you have configured in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_? Pointing the Eclipse Installer to a Java installed on your system instead of using Java as part of Eclipse is not recommended and independent of the Java(s) you want to use in your projects.

Comment: 2 points to check - Check installed JREs, make sure the paths are correct, Check your project JRE lib definition in buildpath, if its same or different.

Comment: Added "Installed JREs". The Run Configuration is Pointing to the configured jdk17.

Comment: That looks OK, it is not at all clear where "openjdk17" is coming from - does that nanme occur on any of the tabs of the run configuration (or anywhere else!)

Comment: Added the Link to open JDK.

Comment: I'm not asking where you downloaded it from, I am wondering where the launch is finding the string "openjdk17" as it doesn't appear in anything you have shown us.

Comment: What greg-449 says. Better choose an _Execution environment_ instead of a specific _Runtime JRE_ (using a specific _Runtime JRE_ makes only sense when having more than one JRE for that Java version).

Comment: This "openjdk17" was part of the launch configuration file but not visible in the GUI. Changing it to jdk17 solved the problem.

Comment: With _Execution environment_ (which is the default) instead of a specific _Runtime JRE_ you would not have such an issue (again).